# why is this rsync command is not syncing?

Tags: rsync

I am unsure why is this rsync command is not syncing?

```
rsync -v -e root@ec2-X.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/log/apache2/USAGE-log.txt splunk-rync-logs/log.txt
```

I see this returned after that command which appears OK.

```
building file list ... done
-rw-r--r--           0 2012/03/26 19:28:00 log.txt

sent 28 bytes  received 12 bytes  80.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

BUT no data is added to the local file that is supposed to be being synced with the remote file:

```
ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 bd  staff   102 Mar 26 19:28 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 54 bd  staff  1836 Mar 26 19:28 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 bd  staff     0 Mar 26 19:28 log.txt
```

Any advice?

Comment: Probably the remote file is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the `-e` option (rsync  version 3.0.8  protocol version 30) is:

```
-e, --rsh=COMMAND           specify the remote shell to use
```

For use such as `-e 'ssh -p 2234'`.

Maybe you have a different version, but that's where I'd start looking.